Besides "make", what notions colexify with "do"?
In many languages the abstract notion "do, be engaged in some activity" is expressed by the same verb as the more concrete notion "make, create". Cross-linguistically, what other more concrete notions also colexify with "do"?
For example, in French Que fais-tu? can mean both "What are you doing?" and "What are you making?" (though the second interpretation may be pragmatically less likely). In languages where the same sentence can mean both "What are you doing?" and "What are you ____ing?, what verbs other than "make" tend to go into that blank?

Not sure it’s worth an answer, since I think it’s rather idiosyncratic, but I’ve always found it interesting how (Modern) Greek τι κάνεις;, apart from the literal “What are you doing?” and “What are you making?”, more commonly means “How are you?”. I get that generic greeting-like utterances form a spectrum containing all of ‘how do you currently feel?’, ‘is anything new with you?’ and ‘what are you currently engaged in?’, but it still feels odd to just identify the first and last of these with each other completely.

There's always CLICS. That's what it's for.'The thing is that people have to know the languages in order to provide cross-language examples...

@JanusBahsJacquet Same in Yiddish (וואס מאכסטו); if you substitute "how" or adverb for "what" then also English (do) and Ancient Greek (πράττειν) and German (machen)

@ba With how instead of what, it makes much more sense (though I don’t get what you mean about machen – “Wie machst du?” doesn’t mean ‘how are you?’, it just means ‘how do you make?’ with no object). The Yiddish phrase is pretty much exactly like German “Was machst du?”, which of course also only means ‘what are you doing/making?’ (if the Yiddish phrase also means ‘how are you?’, I don’t suppose that’s likely to be through Greek influence).

@JanusBahsJacquet Meaning how/adverb for English, or adverb for Ancient Greek and German. In Yiddish it translates over literally from Greek (not implying influence). Wiktionary: Machen Sie sich gut? ― Are you doing well? (reflexive). וואָס מאַכט ער ― vos makht er ― How is he?

CLICS is a database of cross-linguistic colexifications. As with all crosslinguistic databases, its coverage is incomplete, but aims to be representative. It covers 3,156 varieties. Note however that if one language includes multiple instances of the same colexification, these are counted multiple times in the numbers of instances listed here.
For the concept DO (see the subgraph here), they list nine colexified concepts:

MAKE: 100 instances
BUILD: 15 instances
WORK (ACTIVITY): 15 instances
GIVE: 13 instances
WORK (LABOUR): 12 instances
PRODUCE: 12 instances
SING: 7 instances
WEAVE: 5 instances
COOK (SOMETHING): 5 instances

Most of these are pretty obvious extensions of colexification with MAKE, but GIVE (mostly found in Nuclear Trans New Guinea, but also in Afro-Asiatic, Sino-Tibetan, Atlantic-Congo, and Japonic), and SING (mostly found in Hmong-Mien, but also in Sino-Tibetan and Atlantic-Congo) are reasonably distinct, but much less common.

They also have a separate concept DO OR MAKE (see the subgraph here). Which lists 15 colexified concepts:

BUILD: 80 instances
BEGET: 20 instances
PUT: 18 instances
GIVE: 16 instances
SAY: 16 instances
WORK (LABOUR): 15 instances
CAUSE: 10 instances
MOLD: 9 instances
WEAVE: 7 instances
SING: 6 instances
CULTIVATE: 5 instances
SPEAK: 5 instances
COOK (SOMETHING): 4 instances
PLANT (SOMETHING): 4 instances
TAKE: 3 instances

Again most are pretty obvious extensions of MAKE, but PUT (mostly found in Nuclear Trans New Guinea, but also in Uralic, Indo-European, Haida, Pano-Tacanian, and Tupian), GIVE (mostly in Nuclear Trans New Guinea, but also in Indo-European, Elamite, Haida, Arawakan, Pano-Tacanan, and Nakh-Daghestanian), SAY (mostly in Pano-Tacanan, but also Cariban, Elamite, Seri, Austronesian, Arawakan, Tupian, Nuclear-Macro-Je, and Lengua-Mascoy), CAUSE (mostly in Indo-European, but also in Seri, Austronesian, and Pano-Tacanan), SING (mostly in Tai-Kadai, but also Nakh-Daghestanian, and Austroasiatic), SPEAK (in Austronesian, Pano-Tacanan, Nakh-Daghestanian, and Nuclear Trans New Guinea), and TAKE (in Uralic, Haida, and Nakh-Daghestanian) are reasonably distinct.
